# glBlitFramebuffer cause OpenGL error

Tags: opengl, graphics

I want to use multisample anti-aliasing  and save what I draw to a BMP.I use a FBO for multisampling and a normal FBO.I have referred to this article:[GL_framebuffer_multisample](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample).

But when I use **glBlitFramebuffer** to copy data from the FBO for multisampling to the normal FBO,an OpenGL error happens.Now I post part of my code here:

Firstly, create two FBOs:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1,&m_frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1,&m_renderBufferColor);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferColor);
//在FBO里开启多重采样
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER,4,
    GL_RGB,m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferColor);

glGenRenderbuffers(1,&m_renderBufferDepth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferDepth);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER,4,
    GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
    GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferDepth);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);//解除绑定

//generate standard FBO for blitting
glGenFramebuffers(1,&m_frameBufferBlit);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBufferBlit);

glGenRenderbuffers(1,&m_renderBufferColorBlit);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferColorBlit);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,GL_RGB,
    m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferColorBlit);

glGenRenderbuffers(1,&m_renderBufferDepthBlit);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferDepthBlit);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,
    m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
    GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_renderBufferDepth);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);//解除绑定
```

Then draw something:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBuffer);
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    cout << "The frame buffer status is not complete!" << endl;
    return;
}

drawing();//draw something
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

    int temp1 = GLUtils::checkForOpenGLError(__FILE__,__LINE__);
    //blitting
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBufferBlit);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBuffer);

    int temp2 = GLUtils::checkForOpenGLError(__FILE__,__LINE__);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0,0,m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight,
        0,0,m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight,
        GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT,GL_LINEAR);
    int temp3 = GLUtils::checkForOpenGLError(__FILE__,__LINE__);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

    //glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,m_subImageBuffer[i]);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBufferBlit);
    //注意：以BGR的顺序读取
    glReadPixels(0,0,m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight,
        GL_BGR,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,bufferOffset(0));
    int temp4 = GLUtils::checkForOpenGLError(__FILE__,__LINE__);
    m_subPixels[i] = static_cast<GLubyte*>(glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,GL_READ_ONLY));
    if (m_subPixels[i] == NULL)
    {
        cout << "NULL pointer" << endl;
    }
    gltGenBMP(subImageFile[i],GLT_BGR,m_subImageWidth,m_subImageHeight,m_subPixels[i]);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
```

The function **GLUtils::checkForOpenGLError** is to check if OpenGL error happens(returns 1 means there is error happened).**drawing** is to render something.And the function **gltGenBMP** is to save the data as a BMP.They all work well.I find that temp1 and temp2 are 0 ,temp3 and temp4 are 1.So I come to a conclusion: there is something wrong with the function **glBlitFramebuffer**.But why?Is there any setting wrong?

---

**Update:**
When I check the normal FBO m_frameBufferBlit:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,m_frameBufferBlit);
status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    cout << "The frame buffer status is not complete!" << endl;
    return;
}
```

I find that it is not complete.So I Haven't created the FBO correctly?

What's the problem?

Comment: What is the OpenGL error code ?

Comment: @rotoglup : I Have update my question.I think there is something wrong with the code that created FBO m_frameBufferBlit.But I still cannot figure it out.Could you help me?

Comment: Well I understand that you get an OpenGL error. What I want to know is which error code is `glGetError()` reporting you ? `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` ? something else ? You're turning this information in a simple boolean in `temp3`, you're losing this information.

Comment: Also what is that `status` code given by `glCheckFramebufferStatus`? Did you look at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Completeness, it may help you.

Comment: @rotoglup Thank you so much. I have solve this problem.

Comment: Good news, perhaps you could pour your answer to your question then, and accept it. This may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be useful to recall the conditions for framebuffer completeness:

- there must be at least an image attached to the framebuffer
- all attachments must be attachment-complete
- all active draw buffers must have an associated image
- the read buffer, if active, must have an associated image
- all attached images must have the same number of samples

and the conditions for attached images completeness:

- the image must have non-zero width and height
- the image internal format must match the attachment point
  (*eg: depth images must be attached to a depth attachment*)

Note that these rules are a simplification of the [real rules](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Completeness_Rules), that are slightly more complex.